# Python file not created if function is ran in thread

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, file, ccxt

Github repo - [Github Repo](https://github.com/XotEmBotZ/cryptoSnapshots)
I have a function

```py
def sepLastData(data: pd.DataFrame, config: dict, folderPath: str = None) -> None:
    """
    Seperates last data based on config.

    Config preview=>
    config={
        "lastData":['close','RSI','RSISMA100'],
    }
    """
    if folderPath is None:
        folderPath = outputPath
    d = data.iloc[-1]
    toFetch = config["lastData"]
    with open(os.path.join(folderPath, 'lastData.csv'), 'wt', encoding="UTF-8") as file:
        for fetch in toFetch:
            file.write(fetch)
            file.write(',')
        file.write('\n')
        for fetch in toFetch:
            file.write(str(d[fetch]))
            file.write(',')
        file.close()
```

When I run the function normally it creates lastData.csv but when I run the function in a different thread then it doesn't create the lastData.csv.

The project collects crypto data using ccxt and does some calculations on it, then stores the data in different csv files like lastData.csv(last candlestick data), main.csv(candlestick chart data), etc.
The calculations take almost 1-2 sec, but I have to run it threaded as thousands of symbols will have to be calculated and all of them should be at single time.

NOTE: every other function creates their respective file in threaded mode except `sepLastData`

How to run the program->
run the `run.py`
How to switch between normal and threaded->

```py
# run.py
for symbol in config["symbols"]:
    for timeframe in symbol["timeframe"]:
        getData(symbol,timeframe)
        # makeThread(getData,symbol,timeframe)
```

Just uncomment `makeThread(getData,symbol,timeframe)` line and comment `getData(symbol,timeframe)` line.

All the functions for creating files are in `prepData/seperateData.py` in which `sepLastData` is problematic.

Python version - 3.10.8
Required library -pandas , ccxt , numpy

I would like to know the reason for the error as well as fixes as soon as possible.

Comment: What does `makeThread` look like? Where does it come from? There is also no `getData` defined.

Comment: Did you *join* the thread with the main thread? See the various examples on threading in the stdlib documentation.